# Как отслеживать онлайн друга(друзей) в discord, используя discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Хочу написать скрипт, который будет заходить под мой личный аккаунт **Discord** и отслеживать какой тип онлайна стоит у друга(В сети/Не активен/Не беспокоить/оффлайн). Подскажет кто как такое реализовать и возможно ли такое реализовать?

Comment: судя по [документации](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user), переменной текущего статуса нет. Скорее всего, это не реализуемо средствами API

Comment: наврал. почитал [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=status#discord.Status) библиотеки, вроде как возможно

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov а на счет того как зайти не под аккаунт бота(приложения) а именно под свой аккаунт, такое возможно?

Comment: ничего сказать не могу, к сожалению не сталкивался с таким. вам лучше загуглить и почитать документацию библиотеки. Но я, честно говоря, сомневаюсь, что такое возможно

Answer (score 0):

При помощи модуля discord.py-self

pip install discord.py-self

Код как в вашем боте, ничего не мянейте, кроме токена
Как взять ВАШ токен?
Просто нажмите в дискорде на F12 и пропишите localStorage.token
И потом просто в токен вставьте это

Comment: это точно хороший совет? не приведёт к бану?